# Does MessageHandler in WebAPI is the same as HttpHandler in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I am using `WebAPI` to develop a `REST based communication model` for my clients.

To intercept the incoming request and log them, I use a class that is derived from `MessageHandler` and register it in the `WebAPIConfig`.

Note: I never happened to work with legacy ASP.NET Web applications.

When I attended an interview yesterday, the interviewer asked about `HttpHandlers` in `ASP.NET`.

Is the `HttpHandler` so called `MessageHandler` in WebAPI or both are different ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can say that [`MesssageHandler`](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-message-handlers) is to Web API what [`HttpModule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178468(v=vs.85).aspx) is to pre-vNext ASP.NET.

An [`HttpHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227675(v=vs.100).aspx) in ASP.NET has a role more similar to an `ApiController` in Web API request pipeline: it is delegated requests and returns something in response.

Comment: beautifully explained. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: and now in ASP.NET Core, MessageHandler is gone, and it's basically any interposing class you want.